# Warning: 'newdata' has x rows but variables found have >x rows with coxph and survfit

Tags: r, survival-analysis, cox-regression, survival

I have reviewed the other similar questions and I don't believe I have found the answers.

I am trying to do Cox regression with two co-variates - sex and disease status.

Original data frame looks a bit like this:

```
Patient ID: 1001, 1002
Age: 56, 60
Sex: Male, Female
Mortality event: 1 0
Follow up years: 6,7
```

I have called `cxmod <- coxph(Surv(Mortality event, time) ~ Disease_status + Sex, data = original data)`

I have set up a `dummy_df` as a grid as per instructions for this package for the co-variates:

```
Sex Male  Disease_status 0, 
Sex  Female Disease_status 0, 
Sex Male Disease status 1, 
Sex Female Disease status 1
```

I have renamed the rownames as letters since I understood this is what was needed.

However when I call:

```
cxsf <- survfit(cxmod, data= orginal_data_frame, newdata = dummy_df, conf.type = "none")
```

I get the following error message:

```
Warning message:
'newdata' had 4 rows but variables found have 500000 rows
```

Furthermore, if I call `surv_summary(cxsf)` to help visualise the plot - the R sessions gets terminated encountering a fatal error.

Can anyone advise on what's going wrong?

Comment: Welcome to SO,first provide some sample data, second format your question with crtl+k, also maybe ask this question in https://stats.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to provide the original dataset to survfit because already the model has been trained using it and now the parameters exist in the model itself (cxmod).

```
survfit(cxmod , newdata = dummy_df, conf.type = "none")
```